# if row in dict key[0][value] get key[1][value]

Tags: python

i'm not sure if the title is right, but here is what i am trying to do, which should be a simple task.

i have a dict:

```
dict = {u'a': {0: u'1', 1: u'2'}, u'b': {0: u'A', 1: u'B'}}
```

i then have a dataframe.

```
Num       Letter
1           
3          C
4          D
```

what i want to do is

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0] in dict['a'].values():
    [row[1]] = dict['b'[0]] <- this isn't correct, but is what i'm trying to do
```

so I want to calculate the value for row[1] in the dataframe from the dictionary.

i know that i can convert the dict to a df and merge, append, etc, but i need to use a dict for the update.

i'm sure there is a simple solution for this, but i can't seem to find it. does anyone know the proper way to do this with a dict?

Again, i need to use a dict.

Comment: What would be the expected output/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are looking for something more along the lines of:

```
if row[0] in d['a'].values():
    row[1] = d['b'][row[0]]
```

I've done a couple of things here.  First of all, `dict` is a built-in Python function, so I've named your dictionary `d` to not conflict with it.

Secondly, in this expression:

```
d['b'[0]]
```

Reading it from the inside out, it takes the string `'b'`, takes the first letter of it, then looks that up in the dictionary.  If you rewrite that to:

```
d['b'][row[0]]
```

It looks up the key `'b'` in the dictionary, then takes the element with key `row[0]` in the resulting dictionary.

Finally, on the left-hand side:

```
[row[1]] = ...
```

isn't a valid assignment.  You just want to set the second value of an existing array, so you'd write

```
row[1] = ...
```